# Android BLE OutOfMemoryError in startScan()

Tags: android, out-of-memory, connectivity, android-ble

On scanning BLE devices using `BluetoothLeScanner#startScan()`, i am receiving `OutOfMemoryError` when i pass filter and `ScanResult`. Error does not come if i pass only `ScanCallback`.

Scanning code:

```
private void startScan() {
    BluetoothLeScanner scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    scanner.startScan(getFilterList(), getScanResult(),mScanCallback);
}

private List<ScanFilter> getFilterList() {
    List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    scanFilters.add(getScanFilter());
    return scanFilters;
}

private ScanFilter getScanFilter() {
    return new ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("--uuid--").build();
}

private ScanSettings getScanResult() {
    return new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED).build();
}
```

Error:

```
    OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 34873690 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM"
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 34873690 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
                      at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                      at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
                      at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
                      at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
                      at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
                      at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
                      at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
                      at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
                      at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
                      at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
                      at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
                      at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
                      at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:504)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:91)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 34873690 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 17MB until OOM"

List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
scanFilters.add(getScanFilter());
return scanFilters;
```

I suspect this is returning a long list. I would suggest logging this list each time you add a new scan filter.

```
List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
scanFilters.add(getScanFilter());
Log.i("Scan filter: ", getScanFilter.toString());
return scanFilters;
```